# Python - Pivot Table Multiple Columns

Tags: python, pivot

I have a DataFrame with this kind of information

| Circuit | Time | Variable Max | Element |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | 20/03/2022 | Value 11 | P |
| C2 | 21/03/2022 | Value 12 | P |
| C1 | 22/03/2022 | Value 21 | Q |
| C2 | 20/03/2022 | Value 22 | Q |
| C1 | 21/03/2022 | Value 13 | P |
| C2 | 22/03/2022 | Value 23 | Q |
| C2 | 21/03/2022 | Value 24 | Q |
| C1 | 23/03/2022 | Value 14 | P |
| C2 | 23/03/2022 | Value 25 | Q |
| C1 | 21/03/2022 | Value 26 | Q |
| C1 | 23/03/2022 | Value 27 | Q |
| C2 | 20/03/2022 | Value 15 | P |

I need to take that DataFrame and reorganize it to show me the info like this

| Circuit | Time | P | Q |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | 20/03/2022 | Value 11 |  |
| C1 | 21/03/2022 | Value 13 | Value 26 |
| C1 | 22/03/2022 |  | Value 21 |
| C1 | 23/03/2022 | Value 14 | Value 27 |
| C2 | 20/03/2022 | Value 15 | Value 22 |
| C2 | 21/03/2022 | Value 12 | Value 24 |
| C2 | 22/03/2022 |  | Value 23 |
| C2 | 23/03/2022 |  | Value 25 |

In Python, I tried with Pivot with this algorthm

```
# Leer el archivo CSV
df = pd.read_csv(directorio_2022, sep=';')

# Crear una tabla dinámica
tabla_dinamica = df.pivot_table(index=df.columns[1], columns=df.columns[5], values=df.columns[7], aggfunc='sum')

# Guardar la tabla dinámica en un archivo CSV
tabla_dinamica.to_csv('tabla_dinamica.csv', sep=';')

print("Tabla dinámica creada y guardada en 'tabla_dinamica.csv'.")
```

But it doesn't considerate the Circuit Column and I need it. How can I modify the code?

I appreciate the support, thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.pivot`:

```py
df = (
    df.pivot(index=["Circuit", "Time"], values="Variable Max", columns="Element")
    .fillna("")
    .reset_index()
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
Element Circuit        Time         P         Q
0            C1  20/03/2022  Value 11          
1            C1  21/03/2022  Value 13  Value 26
2            C1  22/03/2022            Value 21
3            C1  23/03/2022  Value 14  Value 27
4            C2  20/03/2022  Value 15  Value 22
5            C2  21/03/2022  Value 12  Value 24
6            C2  22/03/2022            Value 23
7            C2  23/03/2022            Value 25
```